# Changing the Default Installation Path in Windows Application

Tags: c#

I want to Change default installation path which is Program Files in windows application When Creating setup. I tried but i couldn't do that please tell me solution.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

- Right click on your setup project
  root in Solution Explorer and choose "View -> File System"
- Click on (select)
  "Application Folder" in the window
  which opened.
- If you look in the
  "Properties Pane" in Visual Studio there is an entry
  called "DefaultLocation". Change this
  to point it somewhere besides
  "Program Files".

Default value for location is `[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]`. These are placeholders variables which are looked up when you compile the setup project. `[ProgramFilesFolder]` is the one which will point to "Program Files" in an English version of Windows.

Comment: Where can I get a list of all the [ProgramFilesFolder] like variables?

Comment: @rolls, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/property-reference#system-folder-properties

Answer (score 14):

In a Visual Studio Setup project, you control the default install path by setting the DefaultLocation property of the Application Folder folder, within the File System Editor.

This, in turn, as you've found, defaults to `[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\\[ProductName]`. You can either replace this property entirely or you can modify these properties.

```
Ex: D:\\[Manufacturer]\\[ProductName]
```

Comment: by the way, in my case it should have been D:\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]

Comment: for me was like `C:\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]`

Answer (score 2):

Here it is

Right click on your setup project root in Solution Explorer and choose "View -> File System"

[image]

Click on (select) "Application Folder" in the window which opened.
If you look in the "Properties Pane" in Visual Studio there is an entry called "DefaultLocation". Change this to point it somewhere besides "Program Files".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions don't work for VS 2012 and above. Please follow these steps:

1. Expand Setup and Deployment Project.
2. Select Project Assistant, bottom you will find "Installation Interview", click on "Installation Interview".
3. You can see the Installation Dialogs, select "Yes" for option "Do you want your users to be able to modify the installation location of your application?"