# Universal Windows Platform. Save files(any type) to Remote Storage - USB (or HDD)

Tags: usb, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to create a simple app using [Universal Windows Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) - basically this application is for Windows IOT Core (Raspberry Pi 3). Mentioned application should support saving files to remote storage ([Remote Devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.removabledevices.aspx)). Unfortunately it should support saving of any file types as this files will be downloaded from internet so this link ([Access the SD card](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/access-the-sd-card)) is not useful. Could you please help me ? Is this functionality supported by UWP at all ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately it should support saving of any file types as this files will be downloaded from internet so this link (Access the SD card) is not useful.

Good question, yes you're right, in UWP apps, we can only save the registered type of files into remote device, you can register all types that your know, but it is unavoidable that downloaded files with unregistered file types are also needed to be saved into SD card. Wildcard here is also not supported to register for all types.

> Is this functionality supported by UWP at all ?

AFAIK, it is not supported. The Design Philosophy of UWP app is for security, that's why it only deals with well-known file types. Handling with unknown file types violates with the philosophy, what if your downloaded file happens to be some worm spam that ends with .bat etc...You may also try to submit a request to add this new feature for development through the Windows Feedback tool, but as my personal opinion, this could be an unreasonable request.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to create simple torrent application. So perhaps it is possible to install application at external drive instead of small disk C? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @Udgin, you mean installing UWP app? For normal devices it is possible, you can refer to [Changing the Default Installation Path in Windows Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028263/changing-the-default-installation-path-in-windows-application) or [How to Change the Default Install Location for Universal Apps in Windows 10](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/change-install-location-windows-10-apps/). But for Iot, honestly I don't know, you can give it a shot, look forward to your test results.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Could you please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263601/windows-phone-8-1-implement-virtualization-for-custom-variable-sized-gridview?

Comment: I decided to put near hundred file extensions to a manifest file. Unfortunately looks like File Extensions in a manifest file for Windows IOT core is not working also. I will try to report this issue to Windows IOT team if I find the proper place to do that. Thanks for help.