# How to set the Default Installation Path in Windows Application duing Installation

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, windows-installer

I want to change the default installation path, which is `Program Files`, in windows application when user is installing the app.
Like i want to set `DefaultLocation` during installation by getting available disk drive names in the installation system ?

Comment: I assume you are not using WiX?

Answer (score 0):

Does this older pot help? [Changing the Default Installation Path in Windows Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028263/changing-the-default-installation-path-in-windows-application)

Or are you looking for a way to check all the different Drives eg C:, D: and E: before installing your application?

Comment: No I already looked into it .. I am looking for 2nd one.(a way to check all the different Drives eg C:, D: and E: before installing your application?)