# how can I change the installation path of a desktop app in the setup project? Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have made a project and I want to make an installable project to install a desktop app. I have added a setup project to my solution. Everything seems to work fine but in the installation process, I'm asked if I want to change the installation directory. When I change that directory to another path it is still installing the .exe in the same path that is c:\ (the root directory). I've read that changing the property DefaultLocation of the Application Folder is the way to change the default path but even so nothing different occurs and the installation is still in the root path.

[image]

I think that from the visual studio 2012 and above there is another way to do that. 
I have also seen that question in StackOverflow but I can't find the "Project Assistant" nor the "Installation Interview". 
[Changing the Default Installation Path in Windows Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028263/changing-the-default-installation-path-in-windows-application)

Does anyone know how can I do that? Thank you.