# Visual Studio Setup Project remember/set TARGETDIR on installation

Tags: visual-studio, installation, setup-project

In a Visual Studio setup project I want to set and remember the TARGETDIR respectively "Application Folder" on runtime (while the installation process is running) if the user is changing the default TARGETDIR.
Because next time the user is running the installer (on upgrade/update) to set the chosen TARGETDIR automatically from the previous installation.

The chosen TARGETDIR can be stored in the registry, but how can I read the registry and set the TARGETDIR before the installation dialog for selecting the Application Folder appears?

Is there a way to integrate this in a Visual Studio setup project or do I have to use a separate commercial product?

Comment: You can set DefaultLocation in the property of Application Folder in Setup Project. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028263/changing-the-default-installation-path-in-windows-application) about this. Hope it can help you. If it does not work, uou can [ask the author on the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects&ssr=false#qna) if this extension has this function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I read some where else that it is NOT possible to override the TARGETDIR before OnInstall :( 
I am using now Advanced Installer. Now everything is working out of the box. Down side is I have to pay 500 bucks.